# My Dialogflow + Firebase bot does not pull data from Bigquery

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, dialogflow-es

I have built a bot in dialogflow and followed the guidelines for integrating it with a BigQuery database as outlined in [Deconstructing Chatbots](https://medium.com/google-cloud/deconstructing-chatbots-how-to-integrate-dialogflow-with-bigquery-267b68f4e795), [BigQuery Docs on Parameterized Queries with Node.JS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries) and [Helpdesk Chatbot  with BigQuery](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-dialogflow-bqml/index.html?index=..%2F..index#4)

The call to BigQuery is made within an async function '**queryParamsArrays()**' which appears to be the problem based on the Firebase Logs.

I updated the package.json with "engines: 8" and  /* jshint esversion: 8 */  in the index file to override the error. Going off the BigQuery docs, I thought this might work. The desired behavior is that a list of wines is retrieved from the database and presented randomly to the end user. Instead I see the SQL query text generated and the list_wines function (whuch calls the async) completes without substituting any values in.

I am going to try rewriting the async as a promise function. Can anyone tell me if I am on the right track? I'm new to javascript and trying to push through it.

#### index.js

```
     // See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
     // for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
    'use strict';

    /* jshint esversion: 8 */


    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
    const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
    const {google} = require('googleapis');
    const BIGQUERY = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

    process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

    exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
      const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
      console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
      console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
      console.log("Parameters", agent.parameters);

      function getPair(agent) {
        // Return wines that pair well with the food or meet other user specified params

        const results= list_wines(agent);
        agent.add('${results[0].name} is a good choice for ${results[0].food_pairing}. A ${results[1].variety} like ${results[1].name} also works!');
      }

      // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
        let intentMap = new Map();
        intentMap.set('findPair', getPair);
        agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
    });

    function list_wines(agent) {
      // Search the database for parameters 
      // Actual values have been removed for presentation

      const projectId = 'my_project_id';
      const datasetId = "my_dataset_id";
      const tableId = "my_table_id";

      const bigquery = new BIGQUERY({
        projectId: projectId
      });

      const params= agent.parameters;
      const excluded= agent.excluded;

      const name = agent.parameters.label;
      const variety = agent.parameters.variety;
      const food_pairing = agent.parameters.foods;
      const conditions = agent.parameters.conditions;

      // Map param columns to those in the BigQuery database
      const SQL_COLUMN_LABELS={label:'name', variety:'variety', foods:'food_pairing', conditions:'food_pairing'};

      var txt = "SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY food_pairing ORDER BY variety) as cat_count FROM \'my_project_id.my_dataset_id.my_table_id\'";

      var x;
      var filters=[];

      // Loop through params to add search params to the SQL query removing blank arrays and empty text
      // Also handles arrays with a single value or multiple values

      for (x in params) {
        // Correctly checking for Array
        if(!Array.isArray(params[x]) & params[x].length>1 ){
          // If the value is text we can reference it in the query with @
          filters = filters.concat(SQL_COLUMN_LABELS[x] + "= @" + x);
        } else{
          switch(params[x].length) {
              default:
                // Array with more than one value
                filters=filters.concat(SQL_COLUMN_LABELS[x] + " IN UNNEST(@" + x +")");
                break;
              case 1:
                // Array with one value - get the actual value
                filters = filters.concat(SQL_COLUMN_LABELS[x] + "= '" + params[x] +"'");
                break;
              case 0:
                // Empty Array
                break;
          } 
        }
      }

      txt += " WHERE " + filters.join(" AND ");

      // Prints output(the SQL query) to console
      console.log(txt);

      // This async function is supposed to query the database but it doesn't get called. 
      // list_wines completes and returns text without results

      async function queryParamsArrays() {

        console.log('calling queryParamsArrays');

        const sqlQuery = txt +';';

        console.log("SQL Query", sqlQuery);

        const options = {
          query: sqlQuery,
          // Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query.
          location: 'US',
          params: params,
                };
        try{
           // Run the query returning an array of objects
            const [rows] = await bigquery.query(options);

            console.log('Rows:');
            rows.forEach(row => {
              console.log(row)
            });


            // Pick ten results at random by shuffling rows
            const shuffled = rows.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());

            // Get sub-array of first 10 elements after shuffled
            let selected = shuffled.slice(0, 10);

            // Return selected 
            return selected;

        } catch(e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      }
    }
```

#### package.json

```
    {
      "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
      "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "private": true,
      "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
      "author": "Google Inc.",
      "engines": {
        "node": "8"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
        "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
        "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
        "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
        "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
        "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0",
        "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^0.12.0"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. Here's where I went wrong:

1. return queryParamsArrays(); within the list_wines function. I forgot a crucial step which was a rookie mistake. You can put this in the code after the async function ends
2. you cannot pass params as DialogFlow provides it to params as defined within options. You have to clean that up as DF doesn't do a good enough job
3. string literals - I did not notice that the code I was borrowing from used backticks instead of single quotes. This fixed issues where the codes was to substitute parts of a string with the results from the query.